# Definition of limits with absolute constant

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I want to show $(x_n)$ converges to $x$. Suppose that I manage to show that $\forall \epsilon>0,\exists N(\epsilon)\in\mathbb{N}^+$ such that for all $n>N(\epsilon)$, $|x_n-x|<1000\epsilon$ as opposed to the standard $|x_n-x|<\epsilon$. Can I claim $x_n\to x$?

Attempt: I think the answer is yes but just feel quite uncertain. Naturally, for any fixed $\epsilon>0$, I would claim that for all $n>N(\epsilon/1000)$, $|x_n-x|<\epsilon$. Does this constitute a proof?

Comment: Yes, you choose the $N$  that corresponds to $\dfrac{\epsilon}{1000}$. Let $\epsilon > 0$. Then $\dfrac{\epsilon}{1000} > 0$. So there is an $N$ for which $n > N$ implies that $|x_n - x| < 1000 \cdot \dfrac{\epsilon}{1000} = \epsilon$

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. This definition is actually equivalent to the usual one, as the constant doesn't change anything. If it works for  $1000\epsilon$ then it obviously also works for all $\epsilon$, as you can scale things in any way you want (by chosing $\frac{\epsilon}{1000}$).